# “Nice to meet you all” versus “nice to meet all of you”

Tags: expression-choice

When we want to say nice to meet you to many people, I often hear people say “nice to meet you all” and seldom hear “nice to meet all of you”.

Is there any difference between these two?

1. nice to meet you all
2. nice to meet all of you

Comment: Both mean you ain't from the South where it's nice to meet y'all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct and used.  In most cases they seem interchangeable, but I think there is a very slight difference in emphasis.

It is very subtle, especially when written.  When spoken, you can put a verbal stress on parts of the expression that change the meaning slightly.  "NICE to meet you all" sounds a little more natural than "Nice to meet YOU ALL".  "Nice to meet ALL of you" sounds a little more natural than "NICE to meet all of you".

"Nice to meet you all" has a slight emphasis on "nice".  You are conveying how you feel about the people you met.  "Nice to meet all of you" has a slight emphasis on "all of you".  You are conveying whom you feel it was nice to meet.

Again, it is pretty subtle.

Answer (score 0):

"nice to meet you all" means that you have met the group.

"nice to meet all of you" means that you have met each person individually.

In the second case, depending on tone of voice, there may be a nuance that it was less pleasurable to meet some individuals than others.